# Insert Only One/the Very First Record Using an Left Join in T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB`. I am trying to join using a `leftjoin` and insert some records into `TableA`.

My `TableA`,

```
Time                             term_id   config1   config2    final
2017-04-19 23:59:00                 8        147       0        NULL
2017-04-19 23:59:00                 9        87        0        NULL
2017-04-19 23:59:00                10        284       0        NULL
```

My `TableB`

```
Time                             term_id   config1   config2       Claims     Rejects
2017-04-20 00:00:00                8         148       0            568.2        62
2017-04-20 01:00:00                8         148       0            569          62
2017-04-20 02:00:00                8         148       0            572          62
2017-04-20 00:00:00                9         88        0            458          12
2017-04-20 01:00:00                9         88        0            459          12
2017-04-20 02:00:00                9         88        0            462          12
2017-04-20 00:00:00               10         285       0            125          13
2017-04-20 01:00:00               10         285       0            123          13
2017-04-20 02:00:00               10         285       0            117          13
2017-04-20 03:00:00               10         286       1            119          13
```

My desired output is,

```
Time                           term_id         config1     config2     final
2017-04-19 23:59:00                 8            147           0        NULL
2017-04-19 23:59:00                 9            87            0        NULL
2017-04-19 23:59:00                 10           284           0        NULL
2017-04-20 00:00:00                 8            148           0         1
2017-04-20 00:00:00                 9            88            0         1
2017-04-20 00:00:00                 10           285           0         1
2017-04-20 03:00:00                 10           286           1         1
```

I want to insert only the changes in the `config1`, `config2` from `TableB` into the `TableA`. So, I did a left join like this, (I don't need `Claims` and `Rejects` from `TableB`)

```
insert into TableA 
select B.[time], B.term_id, B.Config1, B.config2,
        (CASE
        WHEN B.config1 <> A.config1 OR 
             B.config2 <> A.config2 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END)
from 
    TableB B   
left join 
    (select max([time]) as maxtime, term_id, config1, config2
     from TableA
     group by [time], term_id, config1, config2
    ) as A
on A.term_id = B.term_id
```

I do not get what I want. How can I change my code to get only the very first changing value inserted into `TableA`?

Comment: When the TableB config1 sequence is like 285,286,285 how many changes should be inserted into TableA?

Comment: @Serg As of now, the sequence will be incremented. However,my understanding is since 286 <> 285, a change happens and it will get inserted too. Also, TableA is not indexed.

Comment: Tag your sql-server version. It has LEAD/LAG analytic functions since 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I can look more closely at the sample data and output, I can see better what you want (and it's nothing close to the existing code).

Since you're doing an INSERT, based on the sample, it looks like you get by with just this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT MIN([time]) as ConfigTime, term_id, config1, config2, 1
FROM TableB
GROUP BY term_id, config1, config2
```

Since that is added to what you already have, it should produce the expected results in the table (ie: `SELECT * FROM TableA` will produce what you want after this runs.

But if you're worried about accidentally producing duplicate records in TableA, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT B.*, 1
FROM (
    SELECT MIN([time]) as ConfigTime, term_id, config1, config2
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY term_id, config1, config2
) B
LEFT JOIN TableA A ON a.term_id = B.term_id
     AND A.config1 = B.config1 AND A.config2 = B.config2
WHERE A.[time] iS NULL
```

This takes the results from TableB and does an *exclusion join* to remove rows that are already in TableA. You could also write this to use `EXCEPT` or `NOT EXISTS()`, I'm just more comfortable writing the exclusion join.

Comment: @i.n.n.m I re-wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `time` from the `group by`.  I am guessing this `FROM` clause does what you want:

```
from TableB B left join 
     (select max([time]) as maxtime, term_id, config1, config2
      from TableA
      group by term_id, config1, config2
     ) A
     on A.term_id = B.term_id
```

Comment: thank you for quick response, I tried your suggestion, but I still don't get the output I desire

Answer (score 0):

this is similar to Joel Coehoorn's updated query, but still a little different:

```
INSERT INTO tablea
SELECT 
    min_time, b.term_id, b.config1, b.config_2, 1 as final
FROM
    (SELECT 
        term_id, config1, config_2, 
        MIN(TIME) AS min_time
    FROM
        tableb
    GROUP BY
        term_id, config1, config_2) b INNER JOIN
    tablea a ON
    b.termid = a.termid AND
    ((b.config1 <> a.config1) OR
    (b.config2 <> a.config2))
```

Comment: This one is not giving me the output i want. I tried `left join` with your code, still same not giving me the result

Comment: is the problem with the results from the inner select or the join?  you need to be more specific about the result you're getting and how it isn't what you expect

Comment: The results I get is from above code is all the rows from TableB.

Comment: the inner select should limit the rows to distinct term_id/config1/config2 tuples, so that should return 4 rows, then the join should limit by termids and different config1/config2 pairs that aren't already in tablea.  You should get 4 rows inserted into tableA.

What are you seeing from running your inner select?